# 複数のタプルデータを比較して、組み合わせる方法

Tags: python, python3

例として以下のようなタプルデータがあるとします。

```
data1 = (1,2), (2,1), (3,3), (4,4), (5,8), (6,7), (7,6), (8,5), (9,5), (10,7)
data2 = (1,5), (2,5), (3,1), (4,2), (5,4), (6,3), (7,3), (8,3)
data3 = (1,3), (2,2), (3,1), (4,3), (5,3)
```

`data`はそれぞれ10から8、8から5、5から3への全射のように表現されています。(カッコ内の左の数字から右の数字への写像と考えてください)
この`data`から最終的に、10から3への写像を作りたいのです。
どのようなルールでそれを行うかというと、まず、`data1`の1~10の数字の写像先である1~8の数字と、`data2`の写像元である1~8の数字を比較します。数字が一致したところに写像をつなげていきます。これを`data3`の写像先である1~3の数字にまとめたいのです。
上記のデータから例を出しますと、`data1`の`(1,2)`を見ると、写像先である`2`は`data2`の写像元である`(2,5)`に一致します。さらに写像先である`5`は`data3`の`(5,3)`に一致します。なので求める解は`data1`の写像元である`1`と,
`data3`の写像先である`3`を組み合わせた`(1,3)`となります。

このロジックを基に、出力として10組のタプル表現が欲しいです。どなたかこれをプログラムで表現できる方は、是非ご回答のほどよろしくお願いします。

[edit]:

```
data1 = [(1,2), (2,1), (3,3), (4,4), (5,8), (6,7), (7,6), (8,5), (9,5), (10,7)]
data2 = [(1,5), (2,5), (3,1), (4,2), (5,4), (6,3), (7,3), (8,3)]
data3 = [(1,3), (2,2), (3,1), (4,3), (5,3)]

x1 = []
z = []
for i in range(0, len(data1)):
    x1.append(data1[i][1])

for i in x1:
    for j in range(0, len(data2)):
        if i == data2[j][0]:
            z.append((data1[i][0], data2[j][1]))

print(z)
```

Comment: スタックオーバーフローは誰かに1からプログラムを書いてもらうサイトではありません。まずはご自身でプログラムを書いてみて、うまくいかないところを質問するようにしましょう。

Comment: 発想の問題ならば取っ掛かりすらつかめないという事もあるのでは　宿題を丸投げしているという感じでもないし、これで試行錯誤の跡がないと言うのは酷だと思う

Comment: そもそも標準入力などで1~10が与えられたときにdata1をもとに1~7のいずれかを出力する、ということは出来ますか

Comment: @v..snow data1の写像先を1~7の数字のどれかに割り当てるということでしょうか？

Comment: 写像元を一つ受け取って写像先を一つ出力するコードはわかるか、という事です　例えば標準入力で1と入力すると2と出力し、10と入力すると7と出力します

Comment: @v..snow コードを追加してみました。v..snowさんの提示している問題ではないですが、こういうことでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

以下は more_itertools の [map_reduce](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.map_reduce) と [first_true](https://more-itertools.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html#more_itertools.first_true) を使う方法です。

```py
from more_itertools import map_reduce, first_true

data1 = [(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 8), (6, 7), (7, 6), (8, 5), (9, 5), (10, 7)]
data2 = [(1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 4), (6, 3), (7, 3), (8, 3)]
data3 = [(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 3), (5, 3)]

result = map_reduce(
  data1,
  lambda x: x[0],
  lambda x:
    first_true(data2, pred=lambda y: y[0] == x[1]),
  lambda x:
    first_true(data3, pred=lambda y: y[0] == x[0][1])
)

result = [(k, v[1]) for k, v in result.items()]
print(result)
[(1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 2), (5, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1), (8, 3), (9, 3), (10, 1)]
```

Answer (score 1):

元のコードはこの部分がおかしいです。

```
x1 = []
z = []
for i in range(0, len(data1)):
    x1.append(data1[i][1])

for i in x1:  # ここで i は写像元の値
    for j in range(0, len(data2)):
        if i == data2[j][0]:
            z.append((data1[i][0], data2[j][1]))
                          # ^ 写像元の値を添え字に使うのはおかしい
```

このように修正すればよいと思います。

```py
x1 = []
z = []
for i in range(0, len(data1)):
    x1.append(data1[i][1])

for i in range(0, len(x1)):
    for j in range(0, len(data2)):
        if x1[i] == data2[j][0]:
            z.append((data1[i][0], data2[j][1]))

print(z)
```

もっとも、わざわざ `x1` に入れる必要はないんじゃないかとか思ったり

```
z = []
for i in range(0, len(data1)):
    for j in range(0, len(data2)):
        if data1[i][1] == data2[j][0]:
            z.append((data1[i][0], data2[j][1]))

print(z)
```

(編集)
ここまでくると添え字はいりませんね

```
z = []
for item1 in data1:
    for item2 in data2:
        if item1[1] == item2[0]:
            z.append((item1[0], item2[1]))

print(z)
```

同じように `z` と `data3` の合成を書けば `data1`~`data3`の合成が得られます。

Answer (score 0):

内包表記で書いた方がわかりやすそうです。

```
data1 = [(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 8), (6, 7), (7, 6), (8, 5), (9, 5), (10, 7)]
data2 = [(1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 4), (6, 3), (7, 3), (8, 3)]
data3 = [(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 3), (5, 3)]

ans = [(d1[0], d3[1]) for d1 in data1 for d2 in data2
       for d3 in data3 if d1[1] == d2[0] and d2[1] == d3[0]]
print(ans)  # [(1, 3), (2, 3), (3, 3), (4, 2), (5, 1), (6, 1), (7, 1), (8, 3), (9, 3), (10, 1)]
```

Answer (score 0):

辞書で

```
In [1]: data1 = [(1, 2), (2, 1), (3, 3), (4, 4), (5, 8), (6, 7), (7, 6), (8, 5), (9, 5), (10, 7)]
   ...: data2 = [(1, 5), (2, 5), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 4), (6, 3), (7, 3), (8, 3)]
   ...: data3 = [(1, 3), (2, 2), (3, 1), (4, 3), (5, 3)]

In [2]: d2 = {k: v for k, v in data2}
   ...: d3 = {k: v for k, v in data3}
   ...: [(k, d3[d2[v]]) for k, v in data1]
Out[2]:
[(1, 3),
 (2, 3),
 (3, 3),
 (4, 2),
 (5, 1),
 (6, 1),
 (7, 1),
 (8, 3),
 (9, 3),
 (10, 1)]
```

Comment: 各要素の長さは２ですから辞書化は内包表記を使わなくても
d2, d3 = dict(data2), dict(data3)
とシンプルに書けますね。